# Linux boot from Windows boot manager breaks if Linux updates

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I have Windows and Linux on the same machine, same hard disk, two primary partitions.

I don't have grub and I start both OSes from the Windows boot manager.

I installed Windows first, then I installed Linux specifying that the bootloader had to be in the Linux partition itself and not in the MBR

Then I dumped the first 512B of said partition in a file

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 of=/mnt/share/linux.bin bs=512 count=1
```

copied it to C:\ and used BCDEdit to create an entry for the second OS (or just edited boot.ini , in XP times)

The problem is that after Linux updates, (especially when it downloads new kernel headers) the "linux.bin" file is somehow disaligned and if I try to boot Linux I only get a black screen.

Is there a way to avoid this?

If I updated "linux.bin" constantly, would the problem be fixed?

How can I make sure that the very last thing before Linux shuts down or reboots is to dump the 512B and create a new "linux.bin" ?

Thanks